# '&' causes an error in my shortcode when I list the content of the page

Tags: wp-query, shortcode

I would like to list the specified pages with my shortcode, but the problems are with the '$' charachters.

```
function get_page_func( $atts )
    {
        extract(shortcode_atts( array(
                'title' => ''
        ), $atts ) );
        $page = get_page_by_title($title);

        $the_query = new WP_Query( 'page_id='.$page->ID );

        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                $the_query->the_post();
                $html = '<div class="row page-waypoint" id="'.$page->post_name.'"><div class="col-md-12"><h2>'.get_the_title().'</h2></div>'.get_the_content().'</div>';

            }
        }

        return do_shortcode($html);

        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

    add_shortcode( 'get_page', 'get_page_func' );
```

If I use `[get_page title="Questions&Answers"]`, the shortcode doesn't list the content of the Questions&Answers page, but lists every blog posts.
Do I use the `wp_reset_postdata();` function properly?

Where is the problem?

Comment: can you check if you get the page from title or not, try printing the **$page** variable before, $the_query = new WP_Query( 'page_id='.$page->ID );. because if there is no value for page_id, you'll get all the posts.

Comment: it's NULL, that's the problem :/ ..but why does it list the posts?

Comment: It lists the post because you get page_id = '', as argument in **WP_Query**, which is simply ignored and you get all the posts because of default args.

Comment: I understand. Thank you. What do you think how can I use this shortcode with page title or better to use page id as argument?

Comment: you can try using page slug or page id, get_page_by(); function would be of help to you.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the `$title` with `html_entity_decode`? I came across a similar issue when quering CPTs by custom taxonomies in an add_shortcode function.

Comment: is Questions&Answers a page or post?

Comment: @sven: it's a page, I searched for `get_page_by` but no result, but i think `$query = new WP_Query( 'pagename=page-slug' );` does what I need.
@Abhik: thank you, it's working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ampersand is getting encoded, try:

```
get_page_by_title( html_entity_decode( $title ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use `get_page_by_title( htmlspecialchars( $title ) );` to convert `&` to `&amp;`.

`get_page_by_title( html_entity_decode( $title ) );` did not work for me